# Converting `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I 'm getting this error i dont know what is wrong. I checked some solutions but i couldn't find something.

I create 3 tables in a database (PropertyOwner,Property,Repair) and i want to connect their ids.
When i use the following code i'm getting error. I dont have any other problem when i insert them into a database or when i update their values.

```
    properties.get(0).setOwner(propertyOwners.get(0));
    properties.get(1).setOwner(propertyOwners.get(1));

    repairs.get(0).setProperty(properties.get(0));
    repairs.get(1).setProperty(properties.get(1));

    repairs.get(0).setOwner(propertyOwners.get(0));
    repairs.get(1).setOwner(propertyOwners.get(1));
```

These are my classes:

**Persistent.Class**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class PersistentClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
}
```

**PropertyOwner.class**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "propertyowner")
public class PropertyOwner extends PersistentClass {

  private int vat;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private String address;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private String email;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Property> properties;

  public PropertyOwner(int vat, String name, String surname, String address, String phoneNumber, String email, String username, String password) {
    this.vat = vat;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

}
```

**Property.class**

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "property")
    public class Property extends PersistentClass {
    
      private int e9;
      private String address;
      private String yearOfConstruction;
      @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
      private PropertyType propertyType;
      @ManyToOne
      @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
      @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
      private PropertyOwner owner;
    
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
      private List<Repair> repairs;
    
      public Property(int e9, String address, String yearOfConstruction, PropertyType propertyType) {
        this.e9 = e9;
        this.address = address;
        this.yearOfConstruction = yearOfConstruction;
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
      }
    }
```

**Repair.class**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "repair")
public class Repair extends PersistentClass {

  @ManyToOne
  @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
  private PropertyOwner owner;
  @ManyToOne
  @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
  private Property property;
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private RepairType repairType;
  private String repairDescription;
  private LocalDate submissionDate;
  private String workDescription;
  private LocalDate startDate;
  private LocalDate endDate;
  private double cost;
  private boolean acceptance;
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private RepairStatus repairStatus;
  private LocalDate actualStartDate;
  private LocalDate actualEndDate;

  public Repair(String repairDescription, LocalDate submissionDate, LocalDate startDate, double cost, boolean acceptance, RepairStatus repairStatus) {
    this.repairDescription = repairDescription;
    this.submissionDate = submissionDate;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.acceptance = acceptance;
    this.repairStatus = repairStatus;

  }

}
```

do i have to change something in annotations?

Comment: For a detached entity (which has been read from database earlier), you have to use merge(Entity) instead of persist(Entity)

Comment: I use merge but i still have the same problem